# Is there a better way to check for boolean logic

Tags: c#, xml, boolean

I have an xml filelike so

```
<Config>
    <Allowed></Allowed>
</Config>
```

The Allowed tag is read like this:

```
string isAllowed = (string)xml.Root
                              .Element("Config")
                              .Elements("Allowed")
                              .SingleOrDefault();
```

isAllowed is supposed to take a default value of true when

1. The  tag is not present
2. Is present but is empty
3. Has any other value other than true, false, yes, or no.

Here is the code which does this:

```
if (isAllowed == null)
{
    DoSomething();
    return true;
}
if (isAllowed.Length == 0)
{
    DoSomething();
    return true;
}
if (isAllowed.Length != 0)
{
    if (isAllowed.ToUpper() != "FALSE" && isAllowed.ToUpper() != "NO")
    {
        DoSomething();
        return true;
    }
}
```

There's got to be a better way to do this?

Comment: can't you take IsAllowed as boolean ??

Comment: How will I check for 'true' 'false' 'yes' 'no' if isAllowed is boolean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (isAllowed == null)
{
    DoSomething();
    return true;
}
if (isAllowed.Length == 0)
{
    DoSomething();
    return true;
}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(isAllowed)
{
    DoSomething();
    Return true;
}
```

But actually, given your criteria I think `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(isAllowed)` would be more appropriate as it will return true if the tag's contents are "empty".

Also, you don't need the following condition a second time, because if if the condition was met the first time around the function will return (*short circuit evaluation*). This means that the statements you currently have in the second `If` block would never be executed anyway.

```
if (isAllowed.Length != 0)
```

My first instinct to make this cleaner was to take the same approach as Jon did in his answer, there's no advantage in repeating it. However, I did consider this as another good design as should you introduce more conditions it will be *much* cleaner:

```
private static bool Validate(string isAllowed)
{
    var defaultTrueConditions = new[] {"true", "false", "yes", "no"};
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(isAllowed) ||
        defaultTrueConditions.Contains(isAllowed, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        DoSomething();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't know about "else" blocks either :p

Comment: Nesting will introduce more complexity, I think you know that ;)

Comment: Your final code is incorrect. It will execute `DoSomething` even for `"false"` and `"no"`, whereas the OP's code did not. Also, if you are concerned about whitespace, then you should trim the input before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be better off like this:

```
// This deals with the nullity aspect. (The "Yes" is just for clarity - it could
// be any value other than "No" or "False" in some form.)
isAllowed = isAllowed ?? "Yes";

bool isFalse = isAllowed.Equals("No", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
               isAllowed.Equals("False", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

return !isFalse;
```

Basically the fact that you're defaulting to `true` means that the return value should *only* be `false` if you find an element and it's got a value of `No` or `False`, in a case-insensitive way. Note that I've used an ordinal match here - you may want to change that, e.g. to `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

It's not clear where the `DoSomething` method call comes in, but I would separate that out anyway. Write one method which *just* determines the appropriate value, as shown above - and then have:

```
bool allowed = CheckAllowed(doc);
if (allowed)
{
    DoSomething();
}
// And use allowed here too
```

That's a much cleaner separation to my mind.

Comment: On the lines of what I was thinking to do, appreciate it.

Comment: For the middle bit, why not `new[] { "No", "False" }.Contains(isAllowed,  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Ani: That's an option too - whichever you find most readable.